# Calculating the .Sum() in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have the following code where I need to execute 2 Linq-to-SQL statements. If I do not have the `Any()` in the `if` statement, then I receive error when the result is no data. However, I am not sure if my approach is efficient enough. Do you have any suggestions?

My goal is to achieve the following with single Linq statement. I need to get the `Sum`, and get 0 if there are no results.

```
 if (db.BadgeAssignments.Any(bba => bba.UserIdReceiver == newbadgeassignment.UserIdReceiver && bba.BadgeAssociated.CourseId == courseId))
 {
      currUserScore = db.BadgeAssignments
                        .Where(bba => bba.UserIdReceiver == newbadgeassignment.UserIdReceiver && bba.BadgeAssociated.CourseId == courseId)
                        .Sum(bba => bba.BadgeAssociated.Points);
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
if (db.BadgeAssignments.Any(bba => bba.UserIdReceiver == newbadgeassignment.UserIdReceiver && bba.BadgeAssociated.CourseId == courseId))
```

And later:

```
.Where(bba => bba.UserIdReceiver == newbadgeassignment.UserIdReceiver && bba.BadgeAssociated.CourseId == courseId)
```

The two lambdas:

```
bba => bba.UserIdReceiver == newbadgeassignment.UserIdReceiver && bba.BadgeAssociated.CourseId == courseId
bba => bba.UserIdReceiver == newbadgeassignment.UserIdReceiver && bba.BadgeAssociated.CourseId == courseId
```

Identical. `.Any` is \$O(n)\$, meaning worst-case, it will have to iterate all elements of the source to find *one* that matches the predicate; `Where` is *also* \$O(n)\$, meaning it *will* traverse all elements of the source to find *all* that match the predicate.

```
currUserScore = db.BadgeAssignments
                  .Where(bba => bba.UserIdReceiver == newbadgeassignment.UserIdReceiver && bba.BadgeAssociated.CourseId == courseId)
                  .Sum(bba => bba.BadgeAssociated.Points);
```

This does it once, and will return `0` if no match is made while iterating `BadgeAssignments`... and that leaves you with a *single linq statement* =)

The predicate could be simplified further if you encapsulated it into a separate method:

```
currUserScore = db.BadgeAssignments
                  .Where(bba => IsMatch(bba, userId, courseId))
                  .Sum(bba => bba.BadgeAssociated.Points);
```

The `IsMatch` function (`//todo: find a better name`) is the lambda's body:

```
return bba.UserIdReceiver == userId
    && bba.BadgeAssociated.CourseId == courseId;
```

Comment: `IsMatch` won't work. EF will be unable to translate it into SQL and will crash. The OP put two mutually exclusive tags. With EF it will only work if you call `AsEnumerable` after the collection.

Comment: @t3chb0t fair enough. that's what I get for coding in the answer box =)